# Disjoint unions with exact types as React component props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Reading this documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types

...I would expect that to work with a React component, but I get an error.

Here's a simplified case:

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAfKBDAXFYAnArtCgL4DcAUKJFAEILJoBG2ehUJFl40MuA5gGd6cNDU4BjAPYA7AcCgBhegAp0-Adl6CAlAgB8yYuXILlSLDgIRi2igB4l6eElbWoAej3kgA

I do understand why calling `C` as a function with that argument doesn't result in an error, but why does creating a React component with those props get an error?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually just an issue with using exact types for the props of a component. There's [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2711) open for it. [If you take away the union](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN4A+YAhgFxgYBOArgZQL4Dc62+RTAOYBnUkR6oAxnAB2wjGADCYgBQ0hwhoQ0BKUgD4wMljBgSAPMpolyzNhzDB9PIA), and just have a single exact type, it gives you a more useful error message.

```
/* @flow */

type A = {| a: true |};
type Args = A;
const C = (args: Args) => null;
<C a={true} />;


9: <C a={true} />;
   ^ props of React element `C`. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
7: const C = (args: Args) => null;
                    ^ exact type: object type
```